# VB.NET Modify a Bitmap in a function Call

Tags: vb.net, function, bitmap

I'm trying to modify a bitmap in a function call. 
Without the function call I can do

```
'MyBitMap - an existing bitmap of what I want to modify

Using NewBitMap as BitMap = MyBitMap.Clone          'make copy
  Dim G as Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(MyBitMap)  'Draw graphics to MyBitMap
  G.Clear(color.white)                              'Clear image
  G.DrawImage(NewBitMap, -10, 0)                    'Shift Image to left 10
  PictureBox1.Image = MyBitMap
End Using
```

works fine no memmory overflow or anything
In a sub it works fine

```
Sub BMScroll_S(BM as BitMap, dx as integer, dy as integer)
  using BMtemp as BitMap = BM.Clone
    Dim G as Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BM)
    G.Clear(color.white)
    G.DrawImage(BMTemp, dx, dy)
  End Using
End Sub

Call BMScroll_S(MyBitMap, -10, 0)
PictureBox1.Image = MyBitMap
```

works fine,  but if I try to create a Function to return a Bitmap

```
Function BMScroll_F(BM as BitMap, dx as integer, dy as integer) as Bitmap
 BMScroll_F = New Bitmap(BM)
 Using BMtemp As Bitmap = BM.Clone
  Dim G As Graphics = Graphics.FromImage(BMScroll_F)
  G.Clear(Color.White)
  G.DrawImage(BMtemp, dx, dy)
  BM.Dispose()
 End Using
End Function

MyBitMap=BMScroll_F(MyBitMap, -10, 0)
PictureBox1.Image = MyBitMap
```

here I have a Memory Leak and after more and more iterations, it will crash.

I suppose in the function call you are returning a bitmap as well as the fact that BitMaps are passed ByRef so they will continue to exist. I thought BM.Dispose might get rid of it - but it doesn't. I not quite sure how to solve my memory leak (if it is in fact due to my supposition). Granted, I could continue on with the Subroutine but I'd like to know how to solve this problem any way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to create a function in the first place when it doesn't return anything?  The whole point of a function is that it returns something. If you're not returning anything then you should be creating a `Sub`. If you are writing a function ` a return type of `Bitmap` then return a `Bitmap`.

Comment: There's a lot of problems in your code. **First of all**, you never do anything with the `BMtemp` image. Your `BMScroll_F = New Bitmap(BM)` sets the return value of the function to another bitmap. You should remove this line altogether and return `BMtemp` at the end instead. **Secondly**, if you are to return the resulting `BMtemp` bitmap then you can't wrap it in a `Using` block, as that disposes it before the function is exited. **Finally**, you've got to dispose of the `Graphics` object as well. _That_ should be wrapped in a `Using` block.

Comment: Final note: It's better practice to use `Return <some bitmap>` than `BMScroll_F = <some bitmap>` when returning values from your function.

Comment: Set `Option Strict On`. The only code snippet that could produce  a result is the first. In the second, you have a `NewBitMap` object that comes from nowhere. Thus, this is not actual code, because it's unusable. The third is wrong from the beginning, it'll never do anything. You can build something using the first snippet. 1) (as already mentioned) `Dim G as Graphics (...)` must become `Using G As Graphics(...)` <= Note that here, you're modifying the **original** Bitmap. 2) Because of this method, you need to *manually* `Dispose()` the `PictureBox1.Image` before assigning a new one.

Comment: @jmcilhinney in the backgroud, vb creates an object of the same name of the function and its return type. If there is no return statement at the end of the function, it returns the newly created object.

Comment: The source of the memory leak was not disposing of the PictureBox1.Image, manually, before assigning a new one.

Comment: Not disposing the `Graphics` object will also cause a leak. I highly recommend you fix what I mentioned in my first comment as well.

Comment: Yes, Vincent. I ignored your answer because in my actual code, I do dispose of the graphics object. It was VERY careless of me not to include the g.dispose because it brought up the validity of your answer to others but not myself.